# Symfony2 abstract members duplicated on 2nd inheritance level

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I got the following layout :
[image]

Taxonomy and OfferCategory are abstract. OfferCategory define some comme members with Doctrine annotation MappedSuperClass :

```
/**
 * Class OfferCategory
 * @package LCH\CatalogBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class OfferCategory extends Taxonomy
{
   use Monositeable;
   /**
    * @var int the position
    * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
    */
   protected $position;

   /**
    * @var Boolean Wether OfferCategory is for mobile or not
    * @ORM\Column(name="isMobile", type="boolean")
    */
   protected $isMobile;
}
```

I got after 2 inheritance levels, and when I look to the physical SQL generated, I see that OfferCategory members **are repeated twice** : once in HierarchisableOfferCategory and once in HomeOfferCategory (and ListingOfferCateogry).

```
CREATE TABLE HierarchisableOfferCategory (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT  NULL, image_id INT DEFAULT NULL, parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL, site_id INT DEFAULT NULL, position INT NOT NULL, isMobile TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_1E8BECD13DA5256D (image_id), INDEX IDX_1E8BECD1727ACA70 (parent_id), INDEX IDX_1E8BECD1F6BD1646 (site_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE HomeOfferCategory (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, position INT NOT NULL, isMobile TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Why doctrine does that regarding the fact that above entity already got the members? How can I work around?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding the comments done on [Doctrine2 docs][1] about performance impact on large datasets, I finally changed my design in a more permissive way : I dropped the several layers, keeping only the abstract Taxonomy one.

Therefore all fields are contained in OfferCategory (except id in Taxonomy), most of them are nullable. 
The differents type are stored by constats and type field. Not my favorite way, but the only one found. I chose not to put it as answer as it is not.

  [1]: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#id3